# Get part of contents from another url using PHP

Tags: php, url, html

I'm trying to make a script which displays a random drink recipe every time it's run.

I found several sites which have this and displays a random recipe when the page is refreshed, but some of them takes 3-4 seconds to load, and I'm trying to avoid that.

So I found this site: http://www.shotdrinks.com/p/recipes/
...which doesn't have a "show random recipe"-feature. However, every recipe on this site is numbered, so they can be "called" by adding any number between 1 and 11000 at the end of the url. Fx. http://www.shotdrinks.com/p/recipes/4000.

As such, I'm using this code to display a random recipe every time it runs:

```
$min=1;
$max=11000;
$number=rand($min,$max);
$link = file_get_html("http://www.shotdrinks.com/p/recipes/$number");
```

However, this displays the full page, with menu etc. I only need the header, glass type,  ingredients and mixing directions. These are in different divs, fx. the ingredients are in a div id called 'rIngredients'. So I tried this, to "isolate" the div:

```
$link = file_get_contents("http://www.shotdrinks.com/p/recipes/$number");
$file = strip_tags($link, "<div>");
preg_match_all("#<div class=\"rIngredients\">(?:[^<]*)<\/div>#i", $file, $content);
print_r($content);
```

But I can't get this to work, it just outputs an empty array.

What am I doing wrong? And is this the "right" way to do something like this?

Comment: There's a ton of comments coming in wrongfully saying you shouldn't parse HTML with regexps. Wrong, because this is one of those cases where using a regexp is actually fine and a lot less work for the same result, with clear-cut matchable HTML in the source. You should dump your intermediate output and finetune the regexp with [this easy online tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Comment: do you have permission to use this sites contents?

Comment: why don't you use curl?

Comment: @Robert why use curl when you don't need its advanced features and `file_get_contents` also does the job in a oneliner?

Comment: Sometimes when I've used file_get_contents() it showed an empty results but when I've used curl it showed the content of page. Moreover curl is faster

Comment: your preg_match is using div which you removed in the previous line.

Comment: NielsKeurentjes - Thank you! I'll try that out :)
@Dragon - No. As I'm only using it for private/learning purposes (won't be public) I figured it wasn't necessary.
Robert - I was told this was the way to go, and that using curl would be over-engineering it. I'm still pretty rookie when it comes to PHP, so I didn't really question it. But I will definitly be reading up on that if this fails.

Comment: You wrote "but some of them takes 3-4 seconds to load, and I'm trying to avoid that." you want better perfomace but you don't want to change code. I don't get it ;) it's not overenginering it's just improving perfomace.

Comment: @Orangepill - "$file = strip_tags($link, "<div>");" doesn't remove the <div>, it tells the function to NOT remove <div> :)

Comment: @Robert - I have no problem changing the code if it's for the better. But as mentioned, I'm still a rookie - and I'm not that familiar with curl so it would take me some time to read up on it and somewhat understand it. I was hoping to make this work to begin with :)

Comment: you cant steal for 'private' purposes any more than you can steal for 'public' ones

Comment: @Dragon - exaggeration promotes understanding i guess. ofcourse I'm not trying to steal anything, but when used for learning/private purposes only to be seen with my eyes, are you sure I need a permission? I mean, I could just as easily go onto their site and see the exact same thing?

Comment: Copyright only applies when publicly redistributing protected works. Otherwise having a browser cache would already constitute 'stealing'. Reusing publicly available content, which is provided to you for free without license restrictions, in a website you're not going to open up to a wider audience is thus permitted.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: Is that so? Because parsing arbitrary URLs with Regex is always a good course of action, right? What if they change their markup? Even by adding a space they'll break that regex. Please, for jobs like these, stick with a DOM parser. Regex works well for *predictable, **valid*** pieces of HTML. Not for a full document where who-knows-what happened to their markup.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha If they change their markup chances are they'll also change the IDs of the elements, or exchange that `div` for a semantically far more correct `article`, `section` or `aside`. Chances that a regexp survives a who-knows-what-happens are as slim as a DOM rule. Advising against parsing HTML with regexps *by definition* is as ill-advised as any other advise that doesn't take all relevant factors into account.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: Fact is, a regex is more trivially broken then a DOM parser in this case. If you had a piece of HTML whose format is well known, and nothing else would ever be accepted, sure, why not. But not here.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I'd be interested in any actual documentation supporting that *'fact'*. I don't consider it a fact at all, and have several times written regexp-based quick hack crawlers that actually survived entire site redesigns because the subtemplate containing the actual data hadn't changed. DOM parsing could've broken completely since all paths to the non-ID based elements had changed. I'm not disputing the *'fact'* that sometimes DOM parsing is a better option, I'm disputing made-up *'facts'* about universal preferability of one option over the other.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I think the point here is that, regex is inherently more fragile for parsing a DOM than a DOM-parser *would be*. This is, of course, provided that the DOM-parser is not itself a fragile crock of poop, but the backing libxml for the various XML parsing tools in PHP do a damn good job, always (*almost, so very damn near always*) better than home-brew regex would over the test of time in *many* cases.

Comment: In both cases: when parsing uncontrolled third party data the solution is a fragile piece of crock by definition, whether you parse it with DOM or regexp, and in both cases it's likely to break when the source changes markup. Which is my entire point for saying - if you're handy with regexps and there's an easy solution, do it by regexp by all means, otherwise have fun with DOM. I'm only fighting the mass delusion here on SO that DOM would **always** as a **fact** be the better solution for **any SGML parsing problem**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) in this way:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://example.org/path/to/data');

$ingredients = $doc->getElementsByClassName('rIngredients');

echo $doc->saveHTML($ingredients);
```

The optional argument to `->saveHTML()` has been added since 5.3.6; an alternative is to use `->saveXML($ingredients)`.